# How to get any project properties in VB 6? (programatically)

Tags: properties, vb6, project

I'm working in a Visual Basic 6 project, and I have to set some objects values depending on the project where I am. Therefore, I thought that a way to do this is  by getting project name at runtime (programatically) and comparing it with other possible projects names into an if-else block.

Well, I know I can get project name through the 'Project Properties..." menu, but I don't know a safe way to allow me to obtain the project name by code.
I have tried to do this with **App.EXEName**, **App.Title** but it seems to be the way of get application name, and it doesn't what I need.

Somebody can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The general answer to your question is that they are in the App object, as you have already found out.  Now, I'm having trouble understanding why App.EXEName doesn't give you what you need.  Even if your project and EXE don't have the same name, why do you need to reference your design-time project name from a runtime context?  Presumably the behavior you're trying to implement should be runtime behavior; once you compile and deliver your project there won't be any "project" left, just an exe file and supporting files. (more)

Comment: (cont)  In any case, there is a one-to-one correspondence between projects and EXE files, so if you have to set some values depending on which "project" you're in, you have to set them depending on which "exe" you're in during runtime.  So I don't understand your problem.  Can you give more information?

Comment: Hi Bob! I think you're right. But there are many different projects sharing some files and functions, that's the reason why I need to know the name of the project where I'm in (each project behaves differently than others).

Comment: For example, in a previous project I had to load a file that had the same name as the project (user manual). My coworkers told me that I should use project's name instead of application's name, because anyone could change the name of the executable file but not the project's name. This is true?

Comment: My point is that you don't *have* a project in the production environment.  Projects are only part of the dev environment.  There won't be a "project where you're in" once you install your application, only an exe.  Now, users should be prevented at the group policy level from renaming exe files; this shouldn't be addressed at the application level at all.  In fact, it's a very bad idea to do so; you'll have as many different ways of dealing with the problem as you have applications.  So, your coworkers aren't giving you good advice in my opinion.  (more)

Comment: (cont) For a bit of information on how to do this, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).  All that said, you might look into the App.Comments property if your workplace insists on a policy of allowing users to rename exe files.

Comment: Thank you, Bob! Your explanation was very helpful for me. Finally, I  think the best idea to achieve make decisions depending on the project, is to add attributes and properties in the involved classes (properties could give me information about the project, for example the project's name).Or insert a row with the necessary project's data into a database table which contains the system parameters. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Of your two possible solutions, I would use the former.  I suggest you read up a bit on "cohesion and coupling."  :)